# useEffect maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While creating a protected route for a react app using react router v6 i check the auth state of an AWS user on the project. The protection works after the useEffect makes too many attempts and is throttled by the browser, but i would like to stop this error from happening, this is the error message that is received...

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

here is the code for the useEffect that checks a current authenticated user

```js
  const [isAuthenticated, setLoggedIn] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let user = null;

      try {
        user = await Auth.currentSession();
        if (user) {
          console.log("protected route use effecrt");
          setLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          setLoggedIn(false);
          console.log("NO permission");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setLoggedIn(false);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Are there any other uses of `useEffect`?  Is state updated at all during a render?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the error?

Comment: This effect is probably fine, you should look at some other one. Could you show us more?

Comment: `useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render` The error implies that, because of your empty dependency array, this useEffect is probably not the one causing the issues